# Numbers in same row of Pascal triangle not coprime

Tags: elementary-number-theory

It occurs to me that any two numbers $(>1$) in the same row of the Pascal triangle seem to never be coprime. This is obviously true for the row $\binom{p}{i}$, where $p$ is prime, because every term contains a factor of $p$.

But in general it doesn't seem so easy to prove. Is it true? (Maybe I'm missing something obvious.)

Comment: One should recall what "coprime" means (this word is not of general use): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coprime_integers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is true (and *not* obvious), and it is a result due to Erdos and Szekeres. Suppose $0 < a\le b\le n$.

Note first that $\binom{n}{b}\binom{b}{a} = \binom{n}{a}\binom{n-a}{b-a}$ for $0 < a\le b\le n$. You can see this either by just computing both sides, or via a combinatorial argument: The left-hand side represents the number of ways of choosing a subset $A$ of $n$ elements of size $b$, and then choosing a subset of size $a$ of $A$. Alternatively, you can first choose the size $a$ subset, and then for the remaining $n-a$ elements, choose an additional $b-a$ elements.

Using the above identity, we get
$$\binom{n}{a}\ \mid\ \binom{n}{b}\binom{b}{a}.$$
If $\gcd\left(\binom{n}{a},\binom{n}{b}\right) = 1$, then $\binom{n}{a}\ \mid\ \binom{b}{a}.$ But since $n>b$, clearly this is false.